# Swift: Changing HeightAnchor Programmatically

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I am following this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rNtIeC_dsQ

I am struggling to get the height of the container view to change when I choose a different option in the UI Segment Control

**approx around 17:51 in the video**

I declared the var like so:

```
var inputsContainerHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

for the constraints, I now have:

```
inputContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
inputContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
inputContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -60).isActive = true
inputContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
inputsContainerHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
```

for the segment control I have:

```
func handleLoginRegisterChange() {

    let title = segmentedLoginRegisterControl.titleForSegment(at: segmentedLoginRegisterControl.selectedSegmentIndex)

    loginRegisterButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)

    inputsContainerHeightAnchor?.constant = segmentedLoginRegisterControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 100 : 150



}
```

The segment control is set up like so:

```
lazy var segmentedLoginRegisterControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Login", "Register"])
    sc.tintColor = .white
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
    sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegisterChange), for: .valueChanged)
    return sc
}()
```

**I am using Xcode Version 8.1**

However when I run this is the simulator, the input controller view is 100. and it does not change when I click any of the segments.

Can someone see anything I have missed?

Comment: Is there a way that we don't have to watch 17 minutes of video to figure out what your problem is?

Comment: click the video play timeline at that time and jump into the future

Comment: Ok, so I have not coded this myself however I have just watched the video roughly a few mins before and after that time. It looks like you have done as it says. There could be something earlier on you missed? This might not be a SO question. Contact the author brian and see if he can hep?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The part you failed to do properly happens starting at 16:50 in the video. But we can figure out the problem from the code you posted. These lines are fishy:

```
inputContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
inputsContainerHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
```

The first of those lines creates an instance of `NSLayoutConstraint`, but doesn't activate it and doesn't store it in a variable. So the constraint is immediately destroyed. It has no effect aside from wasting time and battery power.

The second of those lines mentions the variable `inputsContainerHeightAnchor`, which looks a lot like it *should* reference the constraint created in the prior line. But the prior line didn't assign anything to that variable. If nothing else assigned a value to that variable, then the variable is nil. Since it's dereferenced using `?` instead of `!`, the second statement does nothing if the variable contains nil.

You probably meant to write this:

```
inputsContainerHeightAnchor = inputContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
inputsContainerHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
```

The first line stores the new constraint in the variable, and the second line activates the new constraint. This is what happens in the video starting around 16:50. What you probably missed is at about 17:15, he says “we'll get rid of the let” while he copies the variable name from his instance variable declaration and pastes it over the text `let constraint`. The line wraps on his screen, his indentation is incorrect, and he does the copy and paste with keyboard shortcuts, so it's hard to follow. You probably thought he just deleted the text `let constraint =`. (This is why when I make videos I try to avoid keyboard shortcuts.)

However, it would be even better to write these two lines like this:

```
inputsContainerHeightAnchor = inputContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
inputsContainerHeightAnchor!.isActive = true
```

When you are sure that a variable should *not* be nil, and being nil is a programming error, then use `!` to dereference it. The program will stop (in the debugger if running under Xcode) on that line if the variable contains nil. If you (and the author of the video) had written it this way, you might have found the error much sooner, because the program would never have gotten past that second line until you fixed the error.

Comment: Perfect. An you are exactly right on your assumption that I heard him say delete the let bit but didn't see the paste. This has happened in another one of his videos where he used a shortcut I didn't know and was stuck for a while. Thank you so much for this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How did you assign inputsContainerHeightAnchor to the containerView height constraint? You can actually make it

```
 @IBOutlet weak var inputsContainerHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And assign containerView height to it from storyboard.

Comment: Exactly what I suggested in my now deleted answer. So, @JamesG, two people have now independently suggested this. Any chance you will consider it now?

Comment: Make the ivar weak is a bad idea, unless you first store the constraint in a strong variable. The statements `inputsContainerHeightAnchor = inputContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150); inputsContainerHeightAnchor?.isActive = true` won't work if the ivar is weak, because by the second statement there are no strong references to the constraint so it's already been destroyed.

Comment: oh yah. my bad. default should be strong. Thanks @rob

Answer (score 0):

The line to debug is:

```
inputsContainerHeightAnchor?.constant = segmentedLoginRegisterControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 100 : 150
```

Now, first thing is to make sure the line is doing what you expect it to. I think it is. But... Is it actually changing inputsContainerHeightAnchor?

- How is this variable declared? Through an IBAction or through code? If the former, is it properly "wired up"? Is it properly scoped?
- Assuming you did all that correctly, the next question is lifecycle sequence. Are you changing it but not refreshing things? Can you call superview.layoutIfNeeded()?

I know these sound like basic things, but sometimes it's the little things that trip you up.

At the very least, strip out this long video to a single function project and see what's going wrong. Two buttons (not a segmented control) that simply change the height (using AutoLayout in code) of a simply colored UIView upon tapping. Then incorporate what you've found out into the larger project.